# Running market intent exits my main application

Tags: android, installation

My application needs QR code scanner app for running properly. There is no problem to request it like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData( Uri.parse( "market://details?id=something" ));
startActivity(intent);
```

After this I am redirected to Google market with predefined application. However my problem is that this code exits my main application. It is not in list. Is this a correct behaviour? When you want to install some other application does it exit other applications? Or am I doing something wrong?

Main goal is to just bring to front my main application to use it after QR code scanner is installed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "It is not in list" -- what list?

Answer (score 0):

Have you write finish() in your previous activity from where you are redirecting to google play activity. If you have written then remove it.

Comment: No I am not calling finish(). But what I can see, the market is how to say it in the same activity, so If click "telephone back button" in the market I am back in the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String APPLICATION_PACKAGE_ID = "com.google.zxing.client.android";

    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APPLICATION_PACKAGE_ID)));
    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + APPLICATION_PACKAGE_ID)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just make like it is. And when the application is installed I just hit back and it works. I dont understand how didn't work this in friday but now it is ok.